# What is: Yellow Flour?

Tags: flour

We were told that `yellow flour` (Italian) can be added to normal white flour to make a good crispy pizza dough?

- What is this *yellow flour*?

Comment: In that use, I'd guess cornmeal... though they could be talking about semolina, since it's Italian. Does the recipe specify that it's a wheat flour?

Comment: Or possibly polenta: "This polenta was made with “Farina gialla di Storo” (“yellow flour of Storo”)." - Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polenta but it seems more likely to be semolina .. oh I just realised that Catija's comment mentioned cornmeal.

Comment: Semolina isn't yellow.

Comment: @GdD : relative to normal flour, it seems to have a bit of a yellowish tint.  But it's all about the background you set it on or whatever else you have for comparison: http://xkcd.com/1492/

Comment: I'm not sure that the recipe literally means adding "yellow" flour. Popular flour brands in Italian distinguish their flours by package color, so there are many recipes which direct you to use "red caputo" or "blue caputo". I haven't heard of a yellow package, but I've never baked with Italian flour myself. It could simply be one more of the color coded variants.

Answer (score 4):

The yellow flour you are referring to is most likely *durum wheat semolina*, which is yellow in color and is often used in making pasta, breads, and pizza dough.

As noted in some of the comments, semolina can come from different grains and other types of wheat.

Please see this  [link](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semolina)  for more information about semolina.

Comment: Upvoting because I'm Italian and I can guarantee that this kind of flour is exactly what Cindy says. It is more refined than normal wheat flour but I wouldn't use ONLY yellow flour to make pizza.